# HandlebarsJS doesn't parse JSON Object on template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

### Equipments

This is my root `.get`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

And this is my Handlebars template compilation within a Backbone's View mechanism:

```
  var Test = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#test'),
    render: function () {
      var source    = $('#TestTemplate').html(),
          template  = Handlebars.compile(source);

      this.$el.html(template({
        question: 'Who are you?'
      }));
    }
  });
```

Lastly, my `index.html`:

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script id="TestTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h1>{{question}}</h1>
</script>
```

### The problem

`<h1></h1>` is rendered on `#test`, **but is not showing the `question`** JSON Object.

### Attention

- I'm not precompiling Handlebars.
- Everything is doing okay (templating compilation, for example), I just can't display the `question` within my `.html`.
- If I pass `{question: 'Who are you?'}` through `app.get`, it is rendered on my view normally.

Comment: I'm not sure I got the example right, but it seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/AEd93/

Comment: Hello @nikoshr. So, I am afraid that the isn't Handlebars itself – it maybe a conflict against Node.JS maybe. Have you nothing in mind?

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(template({question: 'Who are you?'}))`? If the correct HTML gets logged then something is changing your DOM after the rendering. If the wrong HTML is logged, can you try simplifying: change "question" to "a", change "Who are you?" to "x", and get rid of the H1 so your template is just `{{a}}`. If that doesn't work then something is seriously wrong with your Handlebars install; perhaps try re-downloading it?